# Redirecting to login after logout (Identity Server 3)

Tags: oauth, openid, identityserver3

This is my first experience with Identity Server. How can I redirect to login page after logout from Identity Server?

Please, guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Read the docs: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/signout.html

Comment: Tnank you for your comment!
It's very usefull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is kinda annoying,

IDS doesn't support auto redirect.

There's like 4 things you need to do

So to get some kind of redirect on logout you have to add this:

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
        {
            if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
            {
                var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                if (idTokenHint != null)
                {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                }
            }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

to the client code

then you need to add the post logout uri to the client setup

THEN

do this as well

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44306/"
    });
```

And I think that's it

I also added the LogoutUri to the client but I don't think that's necessary

Comment: "IDS doesn't support auto redirect." -- There's a good reason for that too. The http front channel signout spec need a "logged out" page to be displayed to the user to allow time to trigger requests to all the other apps the user has signed into for single singout. If you auto-redirect at signout, then the user will not have a chance to be signed out of the other clients.

Comment: I only said it was kinda annoying :P

Comment: Thank for you answer, but i don't understand some moments.I don't use open id connection provider. It is possible to solve it without setup it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, I'd have to see how you setup your IDS on the client